# Sum of elements multidimensional array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm a student and learn JavaScript. Please assist to find a result.
Task
Find a sum of elements of multidimensional array.
I have following task for example: [[1, 2], [2, -3], [3, 5], [3, 7]], result should be [3, -1, 8, 10].
Sorry for not share my attempt, I have used following, but completely stuck:

```
  function sumInArray(arr){
  let array = [];
  let sumOfElements = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    for (let j = 1; j < arr[i].length; j++){
      sumOfElements += arr[i][j];
      array.push(sumOfElements);
    }
  }
return array;
}
console.log(sumInArray([[1, 2], [2, 2, 6]]));
```

Thank you for any idea, example!

Comment: Use Array.map function here you can check https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: How exactly are you “leaerning”, when you are just trying to completely outsource your homework(?) to us here? Please go read [ask]. You are supposed to at least present your own attempt first of all.

Comment: Hello CBroe, I'm sorry to not share my example of attempt. Next time I will do for sure. I just started learning JavaScript and tried to use following, but completely stuck                                                                                                                      function sumInArray(arr){
  let array = [];
  let sumOfElements = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    for (let j = 1; j < arr[i].length; j++){
      sumOfElements += arr[i][j];
      array.push(sumOfElements);
    }
  }
return array;
}
console.log(sumInArray([[1, 2], [2, 2, 6]]));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const array = [[1, 2], [2, -3], [3, 5], [3, 7]]

const result = array.map(subArr => {
  return subArr.reduce((pre, item) => pre + item, 0)
})

console.log(result)
```

Use [map function](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate the first layer and use [reduce function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to do the sum for each sub-array.

This works even you have more than 2 items in each sub-array. Hope it helps