# How to add arrays of arrays using the for-loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, arraylist, addition

I'm trying to add the arrays inside an array and get a single number from each array. The array looks as follow:

let list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]];

And add the results to the array

This is my code and the result I get is NaN. I already tried editing the code many times getting many results.

```
var num = 0;
var numberList = [[1, 2, 3], [4,5, 6]];
function add(array, element){
  for(let i in array){
    for(let j in array){
      element = Number.parseInt(array[i][j] + array[i][j]);
    }
  }
  console.log(element);
}
add(numberList, num);
```

It should add the results to another array. I can push the items to an array, but my first focus is on adding each array. It's for a project and I can only use the `for` loop and the only method I can use is the `push` method

Comment: `for(let j in array)` should be `for(let j in array[i])`

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to do. You have an array of arrays. Now what should `add` do? Should it sum up the numbers in the subarrays? Should it print something? What is the purpose of the `element` parameter, which you are overwriting?

Comment: I'm trying to get a sum from each array individually, like the first child array in the parent array is [1, 2, 3], the result should 6, and for the second array the result should be 15

Comment: And what should happen with these sums? Should they go in another array or just be printed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum of elements multidimensional array javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62671335/sum-of-elements-multidimensional-array-javascript)

Comment: Also, Don't use `for...in` on arrays.

Comment: It should add the results to another array, I can push the items to an array, but my first focus is on adding each array. Its for a project and con only use the for loop and the only method I can use is the push method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use map reduce array functions

```js
const list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]];
const result = list.map(e => e.reduce((a, c) => a + c));
console.log(result);
```

you can get exactly the same result with nested for loops

> The for...of statement executes a loop that operates on a sequence of values sourced from an iterable object

> The for...in loop will traverse all integer keys (indexes of array elements)

```js
const list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]];
const result = [];
for(let a of list) {
  result.push(0);
  for(let e of a) {
    result[result.length - 1] += e;
  }
}
console.log(result);
```

Please see for more details

[Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

[Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

[for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

[for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Comment: The first is identical to the flagged duplicate. For the second, take the time to explain how `for...of` differs from `for...in` and provide links to the relevant documentation.

Comment: Thanks!! I will check, but I can only use the for-loop to execute the result and the push method is the only method I'm allow to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var num = 0;
var numberList = [[1, 2, 3], [4,5, 6]];
function add(array, element){
  for(let i in array){
    for(let j in array[i]){
      element += Number.parseInt(array[i][j]);
    }
  }
  console.log(element);
}
add(numberList, num);
```

You get the sum of the numbers in element.